# The encoded URL not directing to the webpage

Tags: c#, url, encoding

```
Response.Redirect(Server.UrlEncode("Main/Dashboard_User.aspx?="));
```

I have encoded my URL using `UrlEncode`, but this encoded URL is showing HTTP 404 Error. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Does your url work if you type it into the browser?

Comment: yes it is working

Comment: update with your full URL

Comment: This is a relative url, and you shouldn't encode `/`symbols